# Select values from Array based on name

Tags: sql-server, powershell, dbatools

I have extracted some details of a SQL instance using:

```
$SQLInstance1 = Get-DbaInstanceProperty -SqlInstance SQL | Select-Object ComputerName, Name, Value  | Where-Object Name -In ("FullyQualifiedNetName", "Edition", "PhysicalMemory", "Processors", "VersionString", "Collation", "IsClustered", "ResourceLastUpdateDateTime")
```

What's the best way to assign these values to variables from an Array output  like this:

ComputerName Name                       Value

---

SQL          Edition                    Enterprise Edition (64-bit)
SQL          PhysicalMemory             1571485
SQL          Processors                 40
SQL          VersionString              11.0.7493.4
SQL          Collation                  Latin1_General_CI_AS
SQL          IsClustered                True
SQL          ResourceLastUpdateDateTime 24/12/2019 9:58:55 PM
SQL     FullyQualifiedNetName      PTHSQL13.FMG.local

So I would want to assign `$ComputerName = ComputerName`, `$Edition = Edition` etc from above which I can then use to update a SQL table `$ComputerName`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. First you need to convert the results to a Dictionary, and then create a new object using that dictionary of properties.

For example:

```
$dict = @{ }

(Get-DbaInstanceProperty -SqlInstance localhost | Select-Object ComputerName, Name, Value | Where-Object Name -In ("FullyQualifiedNetName", "Edition", "PhysicalMemory", "Processors", "VersionString", "Collation", "IsClustered", "ResourceLastUpdateDateTime")).GetEnumerator() | % { $dict.Add($_.Name, $_.Value) }

New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $dict

$result = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $dict

$result.FullyQualifiedNetName

$result.Processors
```

The above code should print out both `FullyQualifiedNetName` value and `Processors` count.

Answer (score 0):

Dot Notation is your friend here. Since you're storing an actual object that is serialiezed, you can reference the properties of the stored value using `.propertiesname`.

```
[array]SQLInstance1 = Get-DbaInstanceProperty -SqlInstance SQL | Select-Object ComputerName, Name, Value  | Where-Object Name -In ("FullyQualifiedNetName", "Edition", "PhysicalMemory", "Processors", "VersionString", "Collation", "IsClustered", "ResourceLastUpdateDateTime")

($SQLInstance1.ComputerName.Count + $SQLInstance1.Name.Count + $SQLInstance1.Value.Count); $i++){
[pscustomobject]@{
            ComputerName = $($SQLInstance1.ComputerName[$i])
            Name = $($SQLInstance1.Name[$i])
            Value = $($SQLInstance1.Value[$i])

                }
        }
```

Comment: So this stores the data like this:

Name Value

ComputerName {SQL, SQL, SQL, SQL...}
Name {Edition, PhysicalMemory, Processors, VersionString...}
Value {Enterprise Edition (64-bit), 1571485, 40, 11.0.7493.4...}

What would be the best way to extra the values from that?

Comment: `for` loop, just edited but, havent tested it out due to not having anything to test it with. Just index through the list using `for` loop.